# BI group reporting with SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssas, business-intelligence, business-logic

I do have a general question about BI reporting with Microsoft SSRS.
My company uses MS SQL Server as RDBMS and also has MS Analysis Services.
The goal of my company is to establish a consistent definition of Key Performance Indicators for all production facilities and displaying these as a report in SSRS. In the future we also would like to use MS PowerBI for further analysis.

To achieve this goal it is necessary to re-name and do some calculations with the source data from certain PLC systems to reach a common format and join it with data from our ERP - system.

Therefore my question: how is it possible to keep a common data base throughout the company, which offers the possibility for self-service BI? Do other companies normally develop OLAP-cubes for these purposes or is a "materialized view" in the Warehouse getting to a similar result at the end?

Comment: SO is not a generic discussion platform.. more of a "how do I do this piece of code that I'm strugling with" platform. Your question is similar to.. how do I skin a Cat!

Comment: Saying that.. we are in a similar situation . PLC writes to a DB, then ETL data as needed into a DW and then report. But if anyone knows how to report direct from PLC.. I'd love to know how!